# How to calculate difference between (calendar) weeks in PHP?

Tags: php, date, scheduled-tasks

I need to schedule a recurring task, which occurs once every X weeks, in one or more weekdays. 
e.g. every 3 weeks, on thursdays and saturdays.

Normally, if the task would occur only once a week, I would be able to calculate the difference in days between *today* and the last day when the event was triggered, and divide that by 7 to get the week difference. Since the task may run several times a week, I cannot use this approach.

My idea was to calculate the difference between the *calendar weeks* and use that value to determine if the scheduled task should be executed in the current week:

```
$lastCW = date('W', strtotime($last_trigger_date));
$currentCW = date('W');
$cwDifference = $currentCW - $lastCW;

if (($cwDifference == $repeat_interval) || ($cwDifference == 0)) {
    // run some code
}
```

This code works fine when both dates are in the same year, but there is a problem when the interval spans over two years and the calendar week difference becomes negative.

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: use http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php `$date->modify('+1 week')`

Comment: you shouldn't convert them to dates until the end. You should instead, subtract the current weeks unix timestamp by the last weeks unix timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always include the [nestbot/carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference) package in all my projects. It is a much easier and cleaner way to work with dates in PHP. Actually it extends the PHP DateTime class, so you can even use it alongside vanille DateTime objects.

Your snippet would look like this if you where to use Carbon:

```
$now = new Carbon();
$previous = new Carbon($last_trigger_date);

if ($now->diffInWeeks($previous) == $repeat_interval) {
    // do your thing
}
```